# Why i must do two clicks?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have this code in my `LoginActivity`

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener fAuthListener;
    private FirebaseUser fUser;
    private EditText eEmail, ePsw;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Intent i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserMenu.class);
        eEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        ePsw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                fUser = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(fUser != null){
                    userExist();
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "Log out");
                }
            }
        };
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        fAuth.addAuthStateListener(fAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        fAuth.addAuthStateListener(fAuthListener);
    }

    private void userExist(){
        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference figli = db.child("users").child(fUser.getUid());
        figli.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue() == null){
                    startActivity(i);
                }else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PanelUser.class));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (fAuthListener != null) {
            fAuth.removeAuthStateListener(fAuthListener);
        }
    }

    public void signUp(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
    }

    private void login(){
        String email = eEmail.getText().toString();
        String psw = ePsw.getText().toString();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(psw)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email or password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        progressDialog.setMessage("Login...");
        progressDialog.show();
        fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, psw).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }else{
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email or password wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I open the app and there is already an open session then it works correctly and opens the activity `ProfileUser`.

Instead, if a user needs to authenticate must click twice on the login button to open the activity `ProfileUser`.

How can I fix?

I have to check if the user has already entered some information in the database Firebase. If you have entered the name, surname and the city then you should open the activity ProfileUser otherwise he must aprirse the activity usermenu

Comment: So, what's going wrong with the first "click". Why were you not able to debug this?

Comment: If I make the login the first time then it works with a click. Instead, if I make the logout and then try to login again then I must make two clicks. The error is: DatabaseError: permission Denied. 
But if I wait a few seconds after the logout then it works at first click.

Comment: So then this has nothing to do with the number of clicks.

Comment: The problem is the listner. In fact if i do not use the listner but in onComplete() i use FirebaseUser user = task....getUser() and then call userExist() so work

Comment: Sounds like you are making good progress towards solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've successfully signed in once the User is authenticated, but is only dismissing the `progressDialog`.

Call the `userExist()` after that, so it will be able to do the necessary implementation and start the Activity (`PanelUser` or `UserMenu`)

Comment: When I press the login button, the event onAuthStateChanged()  is activated and then calls the userexist () method

Comment: so `userexist()` is being called thru `onAuthStateChanged()`, but still doesn't doesn't automatically go to the next activity? From what I understand, you only specified the listener, something has to trigger it for the Activity to start

Comment: If I make the login the first time then it works with a click. Instead, if I make the logout and then try to login again then I must make two clicks. The error is: DatabaseError: permission Denied. But if I wait a few seconds after the logout then it works at first click. How is it possible?